# Xpath not working in scrapy despite working in chrome

Tags: python, scrapy

Tried:

```
date = response.xpath('//*[@id="page_match_1_block_match_info_5"]/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/dl/dd[2]/a/text()').get()
```

Print: `None`

```
date = response.xpath('//*[@id="page_match_1_block_match_info_5"]/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/dl/dd[2]/a').get()
```

Print: `<a href="/matches/2020/04/03/"><span class="timestamp" data-value="1585922400" data-format="d mmmm yyyy">3 April 2020</span></a>`

But I need: `3 April 2020`

Comment: Have you tried ending  your xpath wtih `a/span/text()`

Comment: @JustinEzequiel this solved it, can you link to the relevant docs?

Comment: no docs needed; I just looked at your XML. the `span` is a child of the `a` element and you want to get the `text()` of the span

Comment: @JustinEzequiel All the time it is a excellent way read the documentations, references and examples, do not forget that.

Comment: You're more than welcome to post links to relevant docs, @FrancoGil.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a final string into the Xpath Route **text()**.

In your specific case, complete the Xpath route

```
'//[@id="page_match_1_block_match_info_5"]/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/dl/dd[2]/a'

'...dd[2]/a/span/text()'
```

Final Xpath:

'//[@id="page_match_1_block_match_info_5"]/div[2]/div[2]/div[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XPath#Syntax_and_semantics_(XPath_1.0))/dl/dd[2]/a/span/text()'

Example:

Suppose that you want to extract the word **HOME** from this set of HTML's tags.

HTML:

```
<nav class="main-nav mobileNav">
    <ul>
        <li class="page-collection active-link">
            <a href="/">HOME</a>
        </li>

        <li class="index-collection">
            <a href="/featuring">FEATURING</a>
        </li>

        <li class="page-collection">
            <a href="/contact">CONTACT</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

python's code line:

```
# Both selectors (extract_first, get) will obtain the same result.
# Add the text() component as a final str. into the Xpath route.
response.xpath('//*[@class="main-nav mobileNav"]/ul/li/a/text()').extract_first()

response.xpath('//*[@class="main-nav mobileNav"]/ul/li/a/text()').get()
```

Output:

```
'HOME'
```

Explanation:

You need to find a node of text type inside of the actual node that you are visiting.

```
<a href="/">HOME</a>
```

That is the last node that your are visiting before get the text content. Adding text() in the last Xpath route

```
'../a/text()'
```

Will result in the text that the a tag is holding.

```
'HOME'
```

Reference: [Xpath - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XPath#Syntax_and_semantics_(XPath_1.0))